# Connect to a virtual machine on a virtual server using vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, virtual-machine

I have successfully connected to a virtual host using vscode's remote ssh extension. But I need to connect to a virtual machine inside this host. I have successfully achieved this using terminal using `ssh companyname@IPaddress` and inputted a password in terminal.

I want to make this connection in vscode so I can edit files using the vscode environment. I tried modifying the ssh config file but nothing really worked.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so this is the wrong place. But what you need to do is get an ssh connection from outside to the virtual machine -- and that's not related to VS code at all really.